# MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data, resttemplate

I have a controller that performs file upload , i'm trying to post a request to controller endpoint from another service.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/upload/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploadBaseImage(@RequestParam("data") String imageData, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,@PathVariable("id") String id)
            throws Exception {
        String imageUrl = feedHandler.UploadAndSetImageUrl(imageData, file,Integer.parseInt(id));
        return imageUrl;
    }
```

Code from where i'm calling the above endpoint

```
public SupplierFeedResponse uploadBaseFeedImage(String data, MultipartFile file, String supplierId) throws IOException {
        String uploadBaseFeedEndpoint = uploadFeedEndpoint+Constants.FEED_SERVICE_BASE_FEED_UPLOAD_URI+supplierId;
        SupplierFeedResponse supplierFeedResponse =  new SupplierFeedResponse();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
        MultiValueMap<String, Object> body = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        body.add("file", new ByteArrayResource(file.getBytes()));
        body.add("data", data);

        log.info("Request body : "+body.toString());

        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(body, headers);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(uploadBaseFeedEndpoint, requestEntity, String.class);
        return supplierFeedResponse;

    }
```

I'm getting the below error, don't know the reason:

```
[MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Been looking around for a while with no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you are missing `file` param within your request, so you must consider `file` param inside of your request. Also you can add new attribute (`require`) inside `@RequestParam` such as `@RequestParam(value = "file", required = false)`. Purpose of `required` attribute, to make request parameter to be required (if true) or optional (if false).

Comment: Thanks @turab ! That is exactly what I searching for :)